# sap hana sql dates aggregation

Tags: sql, hana

I have an issue with a query I have written for sap hana.

There is basically two tables.

First table is a dates table which contains dates for each single day in a calendar. second table is a results table containing a customer reference number and for each customer reference number a start date and end date. In this customer ref table, I have approximately 4 million records. So essentially in the inner part of the query I would be getting 4 million records for each day since 01012011. There must be a simple way of aggregating the results. I have tried an inner select query however it seems like hana is having performance issues.

I have written the code like this, however this is not optimal.

```
   select date_sql, count(*) as count
           from (
                select date_sql 
                    from  tbl_ref_cal_link tbl_date                     
                       where date_sql between '2011-01-01' and add_days (to_date(current_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), -1)                       
   )tbl_date
            Left join #cust_ref_table M1
                 On tbl_date.date_sql between m1.startdate and m2.enddate)z
```

I would appreciate anyone's help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Group By here
And you need to change the m2 in WHERE clause to m1 as in following SQLScript code

```
select
    date_sql, count(m1.CustomerId) as count
from (
-- dates table here
) tbl_date
Left join cust_ref_table m1 On tbl_date.date_sql between m1.startdate and m1.enddate 
group by date_sql
```